# javascript memory leak?

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory, memory-leaks

I'm noticing some very bad memory leaks in Firefox on the site I've been working on.
FF has been crashing a lot on it and I wonder if that could be the cause.

What are some common causes of javascript memory leaks?
Any tips you can give me to help cut them down?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/ there's one. But you could really just google, 'common memory leaks javascript'

Comment: Please see http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Firefox%20crashes#w_getting-help-with-your-crash - a link to your crash report might be useful.

Comment: Only on Firefox or do other browsers have the same issue?

Comment: One of my leaks seems to be from using XMLHttpRequest but I'm not sure why. I even tried making it global so I could reuse the same one.